# Get the lowest number in a text file

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


set numb=99999
for /f "tokens=*" %%l in (numbers.txt) do ( 
    if not !numb! equ 0 (
        if %%l LSS !numb! set "numb=%%l" 
    ) else (
        set "numb=%%l"
    )
)
echo %numb%
```

I want a more elegant or better way for getting the lowest number in a textfile. 
The textfile looks like this(numbers.txt):

```
42142
242
4242
2421
152
321
1214
123
3424
1221
```

Comment: Batch files are ill suited to what you're trying to accomplish... have you considered learning and using PowerShell for tasks like this?

Comment: Nope. I just want to know if there is a more elegant/optimized soulution to achieve the same goal.

Comment: @Surprisor: http://codereview.stackexchange.com is a more suited place to ask this question.

Comment: @Daniel Mann What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what you have posted would always show `0` as the result because you are initializing the variable to `0` which is already lower than any value you are comparing to.

That aside, batch doesn't really have "query" functionality, so you essentially have to iterate through every value. Your code is pretty much right on, but if you want to clean it up a bit, you could try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Initialize to a high value.
set numb=99999
for /f "tokens=*" %%l in (numbers.txt) do (
    REM Only need to compare the current against the processing value.
    if %%l LSS !numb! set "numb=%%l" 
)
echo %numb% 
endlocal
```

Alternately, you could shorten your entire `FOR` statement:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set numb=99999
for /f %%l in (numbers.txt) do if %%l LSS !numb! set "numb=%%l" 
echo %numb%

endlocal
```

Comment: This will work perfectly as long as at least one of the numbers is <= 2147483647 (as are all the numbers in the example). The maximum value supported by batch is 2147483647. IF treats any value > 2147483647 as being equal to 2147483647. (It would be unusual for this limitation to be a problem for this application)